# Express.js: req.body is empty when using form-data

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, node.js, express

[snapshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M74wg.png) req.body is empty when I send data using form-data in my Express.js application. However, when I send data using raw JSON, I receive the expected object in req.body. Here's my setup:

**This is my index.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//database
require("./db/conn");

//middlewares
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(cors());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
const userRouter = require("./routes/UserRoutes");
const authRouter = require("./routes/AuthRouter");

server.use("/user", userRouter);
server.use("/auth", authRouter);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**This is route**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Auth } = require("../middlewares/auth");

const {
  Login,
  UpdateUser,
  Dashboard,
  Register,
  Posts,
} = require("../controllers/UserController");

router.post("/register", Register);
router.post("/login", Login);
router.put("/update/:id", Auth, UpdateUser);
router.get("/dashboard", Auth, Dashboard);
router.get("/getposts", Auth, Posts);

module.exports = router;
```

**This is controller**

```
const UserModel = require("../model/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const Register = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  // if (!name || !email || !password) {
  //   return res.status(400).json({ error: "All fields are required" });
  // }
  // try {
  //   const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
  //   if (user) {
  //     return res.status(400).json({ error: "User already exists" });
  //   }

  //   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  //   const newUser = new UserModel({
  //     name,
  //     email,
  //     password: hashedPassword,
  //   });
  //   const saveUser = await newUser.save();
  //   res
  //     .status(201)
  //     .json({ message: "User registered successfully", user: saveUser });
  // } catch (error) {
  //   res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong at the server" });
  // }
};

const Login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "All fields are required" });
  }

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Invalid login details" });
    }
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid login credentials" });
    }
    const payload = {
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
    };
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
      expiresIn: "1m",
    });
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
      expiresIn: "10d",
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "login sucessfull",
      isLogged: "true",
      data: payload,
      accesstoken: accessToken,
      refreshtoken: refreshToken,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong at the server" });
  }
};

const UpdateUser = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;

  req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: userId });
    if (!user)
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "no user found with this id" });

    const updatedUser = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      req.body,
      {
        new: true,
      }
    );

    if (updatedUser) {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "user updated  sucessfully", data: updatedUser });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "something went bad at server " + e });
  }
};

const Dashboard = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Welcome to the dashboard" });
};

const Posts = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "post request" });
};

const getAllData = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "get data" });
};
module.exports = { Login, UpdateUser, Dashboard, Posts, Register };
```

I've already tried adjusting the middleware order, but the issue persists. Any insights into what might be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `req.fields` instead. I've added an answer with an example using the `app.post()` method for you.

Comment: What content-type is the client sending?  And, do you have middleware to read and parse that content-type?  If it's sending `"multipart/form-data"`, then I don't see any middleware in your server code that reads and parses that content-type.

Comment: why are you using both `express.urlencoded` AND `bodyParser.urlencoded`? you should use one OR the other

Comment: Do you understand that the body of an incoming POST or PUT request is only read by middleware in Express and that middleware must be looking for the exact content-type that your client is sending.  It seems likely that your client is sending a content-type that you don't have any middleware to read and parse and thus, there is no data for the body of the request anywhere in the `req` object.  The very first thing to do is to either configure the client to send a content-type you already have middleware for or to get middleware for the content-type that it is sending.

Comment: `express.urlencoded()` only handles the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

Answer (score 0):

**After adding multer middlware its working fine** (Multer.js)

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single();

module.exports = upload;
```

**This code here is for handling files**

```
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        cb(null, uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname));
      },
    });
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single();
```

above code is for handling files .since im handling files on my project im using above configuration u can omit the configuration . refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer for more information
**Im using this midleware in routes here**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Auth } = require("../middlewares/auth");

const upload = require("../middlewares/FileUpload");

const {
  Login,
  UpdateUser,
  Dashboard,
  Register,
  Posts,
} = require("../controllers/UserController");

router.post("/register", upload, Register);
router.post("/login", Login);
router.put("/update/:id", Auth, UpdateUser);
router.get("/dashboard", Auth, Dashboard);
router.get("/getposts", Auth, Posts);

module.exports = router;
```

im using upload  on router.post("/register,upload,Register).
things working fine.

if u send data through postman via form-data use multer middlware . express by default accepts only raw data in json format .

Answer (score -1):

When sending data to Express.js, if you're using the FormData() API, Use a middleware like `Formidable()` to gather data in `req.fields` rather than `req.body`.

For example:

```js
const formidable = require('express-formidable');
// Use Formidable
app.use(formidable());
const uri = 'https://my.example.com/';

app.post(uri, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.fields); // Will give your your POST data
});
```

Comment: not working while im console logging req.fields im getting undefined

Comment: where did you read this misinformation?

Comment: It's always worked for me? I had the exact same issue and this is what solved it.

Comment: You must have been using some middleware (that the OP isn't using) for some content-type that put a result in `req.fields`.

Comment: Nope, I'm using the same middleware. Only difference is I'm using only bodyparser and not both bodyparser and `express.urlencoded`

Comment: i tried by removing express.urlencoded and express.json() still the same problem

Comment: Trust me, I've tried it because I basically had the same issue, and I believe it has something to do with the content-type header sent. However when sending non-FormData() component data, it'll show up in req.body. Otherwise the data will show up in req.fields.

Comment: `req.fields` does not seem to be documented anywhere in `express` documentation

Comment: using postman . when i send raw with json its working .when i switch to form-data its not working

Comment: Forgive me, you are correct--I've been using it for so long I took it for granted. The middleware using `req.fields` is Formidable() and I simply overlooked that OP wasn't using this.

Comment: i;m not using FormData() api im just sending data in the form of from-data through postman

Comment: what are your request headers -specifically, `content-type` (actually, this answer is NOT the place to ask this :p )

Comment: mutipart/form-data

Comment: Okay sorry. It was misleading and I thought you were using the built in FormData API

Comment: its ok and thanks for responding ❤️

Comment: added snapshot of postman kindly go through it...

Comment: i got the solution just used multer as middleware and tadaaaa

Comment: I'm not familiar with Post-Man, so I can't speak for that--however regular FormData data works well with Formidable hence my answer. But glad you got it working

Comment: thanks @quietWind01  for your time and response . have a great day ahead ❤️

Comment: closing my issue here .....bye